# PHP write to included file

Tags: php, file, include

I need to include one PHP file and execute function from it.
After execution, on end of PHP script I want to append something to it.

But I'm unable to open file. It's possible to close included file/anything similar so I'll be able to append info to PHP file.

```
include 'something.php';
echo $somethingFromIncludedFile;

//Few hundred lines later

$fh = fopen('something.php', 'a') or die('Unable to open file');
$log = "\n".'$usr[\''.$key.'\'] = \''.$val.'\';';
fwrite($fh, $log);
fclose($fh);
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do it this way? I mean it's a bit odd. you are trying to update a file that is already included... it's wrong way to whatever you are trying to do...

Comment: this is not a real question and should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

In general you never should modify your PHP code using PHP itself. It's a bad practice, first of all from security standpoint. I am sure you can achieve what you need in other way.

Comment: Yes I can achieve it in different way, this is "experiment" I'm working on so this will be the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you please describe what are you trying to achieve with this method?

Comment: Simple saving system, I know it can be done in differend ways. I tried hashmap saving, so I append $val['nevvar'] = 'newfile'; And I want to use $val['nevvar'] in code before appending new one.

Comment: Use database or files if you need to save some data for reading or modifying later.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex says, self-modifying code is very, VERY dangerous. And NOT seperating data from code is just dumb. On top of both these warnings, is the fact that PHP arrays are relatively slow and do not scale well (so you could file_put_contents('data.ser',serialize($usr)) / $usr=unserialize(file_get_contents('data.ser')) but it's only going to work for small numbers of users).

Then you've got the problem of using conventional files to store data in a multi-user context - this is possible but you need to build sophisticated locking queue management. This usually entails using a daemon to manage the queue / mutex and is invariably more effort than its worth.

Use a database to store data.

Answer (score -1):

As you already know this attempt is not one of the good ones. If you REALLY want to include your file and then append something to it, then you can do it the following way.
Be aware that using eval(); is risky if you cannot be 100% sure if the content of the file does not contain harmful code.

```
//  This part is a replacement for you include
$fileContent = file_get_contents("something.php");
eval($fileContent);
//  your echo goes here

//  billion lines of code ;)

//  file append mechanics
$fp = fopen("something.php", "a") or die ("Unexpected file open error!");
fputs($fp, "\n".'$usr[\''.$key.'\'] = \''.$val.'\';');
fclose($fp);
```